# Select rank of single row

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, rank

```
CREATE TABLE Player (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  xp BIGINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Player (id, xp) VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO Player (id, xp) VALUES (2, 150);
INSERT INTO Player (id, xp) VALUES (3, 250);
INSERT INTO Player (id, xp) VALUES (4, 125);
INSERT INTO Player (id, xp) VALUES (5, 500);
```

This query:

```
SELECT id, xp, RANK() over (ORDER BY xp DESC) 'rank' FROM Player;
```

Produces these results:

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | xp  | rank |
+----+-----+------+
|  5 | 500 |    1 |
|  3 | 250 |    2 |
|  2 | 150 |    3 |
|  4 | 125 |    4 |
|  1 | 100 |    5 |
+----+-----+------+
```

But when I add WHERE id = '.....', the rank comes back as `1`.

I know that this is because it's now ranking over just one row, so it'll always be `1`.

But how would I select the correct rank just for a single row? Is the RANK() function still appropriate for this?

I don't mind about duplicate scores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter the result using an outer query.

Try:

```
SELECT id,xp,rnk
FROM (  SELECT id, 
               xp,  
               RANK() over (ORDER BY xp DESC) rnk 
        FROM Player
     ) tbl 
where id=2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/m6a8Tc67

Comment: Will this rank the entirety of the Player table first and then select the single row or will the MySQL optimiser detect that anything after the row with `id=2` is ranked will not affect the final result? Thinking that `SELECT 1+COUNT(*) as rnk FROM Player WHERE xp < (SELECT xp FROM Player WHERE id = 2)` may perhaps be preferable.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't think the query gives the correct results, it is a coincidence with id=2. Consider id =3  in which the rank should be 2  . The query proposed by you will result give 4 as a result . A better explanation [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tFBFP4nS).

Comment: Ah I missed the rank was descending, So `SELECT 1+COUNT(*) as rnk FROM Player WHERE xp > (SELECT xp FROM Player WHERE id = 2)` then

Comment: @MartinSmith it seems that it works as expected and I can't think of a case in which it wont. Nice solution, as per the performance part  it need to be tested , specially with a large amount. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: For my question, I don't mind about duplicate scores, will edit that in

Comment: Given an index on xp, will this query be better than O(n)?

Comment: @MartinSmith I created an account here just to tell you this answer is brilliant.